# pandas.interval_range end time is smaller than start time Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in here that  I am trying to use pandas interval_range to create a range.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time1': ['22:00', '6:30', '12:30'], 'time2': ['1:00', '12:30', '19:30'], 'Val':['a','b','c']})
df1['time1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time1'])
df1['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time2'])
df1.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left = df1.time1, right = df1.time2)
```

However, since some of the time2 are smaller than time1 values, I keep getting the following err:

```
ValueError: left side of interval must be <= right side
```

What I am trying to is to create a range and return df1.Val for a specific time like this:

```
df.loc['22:30','Val']= a
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html. What is your goal?

Comment: @MatthewBorish I have edited the question and added the goal.

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem? If not, let me know what else you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a selection using your two time cols rather than the interval idx.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time1': ['22:00', '6:30', '12:30'], 'time2': ['1:00', '12:30', '19:30'], 'Val':['a','b','c']})
df1['time1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time1'])
df1['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time2'])

# replace datetimes as needed
df2 = df1.loc[(df1['time1'] >= '2021-03-16 02:00:00') & (df1['time2'] <= '2021-03-16 01:00:00')]

print(df2)

    time1               time2               Val
0   2021-03-16 22:00:00 2021-03-16 01:00:00 a
```